# Advanced regex - match only the first occurence of a file when global modifier set

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

In my editor, I try to put a regex on lots of files, so that if it finds the jquery dollar function `$`, that it makes the juqery function is loaded with `const $ = require('jquery');`

So basically, if I have files like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn-toggle-achievement').on('click', function (e) {
        var button = e.target;
        var el = $(button);
        $.post('/achievements_ajax/toggle_achievement', {
            status: el.data('enable'),
            achievement_id: el.data('achievement-id')
        });
    });
});
```

And I want to write a regex to replace the first occurence of `$` with `const $ = require('jquery');\n`. I use the replace utility in my editor. The final result should be like this.

```
const $ = require('jquery');
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn-toggle-achievement').on('click', function (e) {
        var button = e.target;
        var el = $(button);
        $.post('/achievements_ajax/toggle_achievement', {
            status: el.data('enable'),
            achievement_id: el.data('achievement-id')
        });
    });
});
```

This is what I have got so far:
https://regex101.com/r/ooHn9H/1

But at this moment it replaces any occurence of `$`. I only want to replace the first. Can I make sure that the regex matches only the first occurence? Maybe I need a negative lookbehind to check if `$` is already matched before?

Comment: Well written question.  Thanks for the link to what you've got so far.

Comment: `(const\s*\$\s*=\s*require\('jquery'\);\n|)(.*\$\(|\$\.)` and `const $ = require('jquery');\n$2`. See: https://regex101.com/r/ooHn9H/2. It'll replace every occurrence and every non-occurrence with the string you want

Comment: It doesn't work if I put the global flag on @ctwheels, which is the only option in my editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Regex:

`^([^$]*)(?=\$)`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ooHn9H/6)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the String
- `[^$]*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character which is not a `$`. The parenthesis are this part in the group. Later, anything captured in this group will be replaced by contents of this group along with the line `const $ = require('jquery');\n` as shown in the demo.
- `(?=\$)` - Positive lookahead to validate whatever is matched until now is followed by a `$`

Comment: Thanks, very well explained!

Answer (score 3):

In your regex, you have the global flag set, which means it will replace every occurrence.  Turn off the global flag and you'll have what you want.

**Edit:** If you can't turn off the global flag, match *everything* from the first $ on:

```
(\$(?:.|[\r\n\u2028\u2029])*)
```

Comment: But I can't do this in my regex utility of my editor.